# How to control this system by using a single Opamp circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier

Below is part of a circuit where an op-amp is creating a 10sec delay by C1 and R4:
[image]
(please left-click to enlarge)

The goal is that: 
One will push one of the  push-button (one of the Myswitch in the schematic) and the magnet-group(R1 L1 which represents four electromagnets in series) 
will get magnetized for 10 seconds and after 10 seconds the op-amp output will go off and the Q1 will be off hence the magnet will be off.
LED will be ON untill the electromagnet current is off so one can repeat the experiment when the LED is OFF.

But I need to make twenty of these circuits to control them separately so there will be twenty switches as follows(I could only draw 3 here):
[image]

**My question is:**

1-) Could there be way to use only one op-amp circuit and twenty switch instead? 
In that case is it possible that when one of the button is pushed(lets say push button N is pushed) only one of the magnet-group(group N) will get powered?

2-) Is  R11, R8 values good for LM324 and TIP120? In simulation LM324 sources around 25mA. I chose LM324 in this case, would it be better to chose a 555 timer? Precision is not so critical, the delay could be 9 seconds upto 12 seconds.

Comment: If you wanted to, you could use One op-amp circuit. The way I see you doing it would require switches AND a push button, though. You would use one timing circuit, and just use switches to connect the bases of your transistors to the output of said timing circuit. you'd have to be careful not to have too many connected to your timing circuit, though, or they may draw too much current for the op amp to handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You mean: one opamp-timer for all 20 outputs. Sure that is possible but then you would need extra circuitry to detect which switch was pressed and only enable the corresponding output. In the end that would probably be as complex as using 20 opamps.

2) The TIP120 is a darlington transistor so pushing 25 mA into its base is overkill ! The minimum Hfe is 1000 so if you would switch 10 A then only 10 mA would suffice. I would double R11 to 1 kΩ making life a bit easier for the LM324.

But if you want something more simple why not replace the opamp timers with a (I hate to say this, me being a very analog type of person :-) ) microcontroller ?

Or replace the TIP122 with a power NMOSFET and make something very simple like this:

I see your supply for the magnets is 48 V, this might be too much for the gate-source of the MOSFET. If so you could derive a lower voltage from that 48 V and use that for the timer part. The NMOSFET usually only needs 5 - 10 V to fully conduct. To adjust the 10 seconds there's a trimmer. If your 1 uF capacitors are accurate enough you might need only a singe resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffX3iP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I simulated your last suggestion by drawing the schematics as here: https://s16.postimg.org/lq7mrxc11/faktitled.png Maybe I should use this one since this doesn't require any op-amp. But I have issues here: 1-) But setting R3 and R4(in my schematic in the link R2 and R3) with 1uF doesnt make 10 sec. I think they should be some mega-ohm level? Did you simulate this before? 2-) D1 in your schematics is upside down. Is D1 is a specific LED used as a flywheel diode? If so, shouldn't cathode side be connected to the supply like the one in my question? 3-) Which power MOSFET would you recommend?

Comment: Indeed you have to tweak R3, R4 and C1 for the correct timing, I just sucked some values out of my thumb ;-) NO, I did not simulate this circuit, that's your job. D1 is the LED, if you want a flyback diode then indeed it needs to be the other way round (cathode to supply) but often the NMOSFET will already have a diode which might give enough protection already. I have no recommendation for the NMOSFET, any type which can handle the current and the voltage will do.

Comment: thanks this would make thing much cheaper and easier to implement. just one "last" question: would using opamp as i did bring any advantages in this scenario? thanks

Comment: The only advantage of using an opamp or a 555 timer is the more abrupt switching off of the transistor. The simple NMOS circuit switches on abruptly (the capacitor is charged quickly) but switching off is more gradual. It is up to you if this is acceptable or not.

Comment: Just read it again. One thing Im not sure. You have written " The minimum Hfe is 1000 so if you would switch 10 A then only 10 mA would suffice."  But here in datasheet: https://art511.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tip120.pdf at page 3 hfe=1000 only at 4V right? Shouldnt we use 250 instead for current gain in Figure 2?

Comment: Another thing is I use here lm324 as a comparator at 9V rail voltage. But unlike in a comparator it outputs around 7.2V instead of 9V. Why do you think that voltage drop happens? thanks

Comment: *at page 3 hfe=1000 only at 4V right?* No, that Vce = 4 V means it is measured (and guaranteed) at Vce = 4 V. As Vce gets lower you get closer to saturation and then the **intrinsic Hfe of the transistor** is still 1000 **but** due to saturation effects you might not "see" that Ic/Ib ratio. Hfe is an intrinsic property of a transistor (defined by doping ratios) and constant over many parameters. But it depends how you use the transistor if you actually get that current gain.

Comment: because i just encountered this tutorial it says we need to use 250 thats why im confused now: https://teachmetomake.wordpress.com/how-to-use-a-transistor-as-a-switch/

Comment: *LM324 outputs around 7.2V instead of 9V.* That is a limitation of the output stage of the LM324. On page 1 of the datasheet is says: "Large Output Voltage Swing 0 V to V+ − 1.5 V" What they mean is that the output can go up to Vcc - 1.5 V, if you do not load it ! If you draw current, it might be even less (the 1.5 V might become 2 V). The output stage of the LM324 is an NPN darlington, see the schematic so it makes sense it behaves like it does. If you want full swing at the output you need a better opamp.

Comment: Hfe in saturation is confusing to many people ! Seach here on this site and you'll see. Using 250 for the Hfe when in saturation is a bit of an arbitrary choice. Like I wrote, the **real** Hfe of the transistor is 1000 but when in saturation you're not using that, you feed the transistor with extra base current so that is deeply in saturation. If you need to make Ib 2 x or 4 x or even 10 x larger than Ic / Hfe is a personal choice. Since the Hfe is 1000 is already the very minimum, a factor 2 would be good enough.

Comment: Also, this TIP120 is a darlington transistor, feeding it more base current doesn't help much as it will always have more voltage drop across Vce compared to a single transistor. This is because in a darlington the "small" transistor also needs some Vce and this comes on top of the Vbe which the "large" transistor needs. In practice I expect that you will see almost no difference in voltage drop across the TIP120 when using Ib = Ic / 250 or Ib = Ic/1000

Comment: sorry for digging it too much but i have to be sure before i build 20 of them. i'm about to decide your version since it is simpler to solder and doesnt require an extra power supply. i found this mosfet http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/SGSThomsonMicroelectronics/mXqsvv.pdf in its max ratings Gate-source Voltage is +-20V. but my supply voltage (in your diagram supply) will be 48V. so it exceeds Vgs. how can i work around this? thanks

Comment: That's OK, the simplest solution I can think of is to add 2 components near the gate to limit the voltage. I'll make an update to the schematic in the question.

Comment: There, a resistor and a Zener should do the job. I am unsure if the NMOSFET needs cooling, probably not but keep an eye on their temperature. As they switch off, this is somewhat slow making the MOSFET dissipate some power. As this is only for a few seconds it might be OK though.

Comment: If it is possible could u add back the previous version of this for 12V supply. You have drawn at the beginning then you made an edit. But now I think I will use 12V supply. was that something like that: https://s12.postimg.org/4lmtu2oot/image.png is the LED in right place?

Comment: Sure, let me add the old version, it's easy.

Comment: That link is unusable to me. The LEDs are in my schematic. I make them run at 5mA then you can use a standard 0.25W, 10 kohm resistor. Making the LED run from 12V would be more complicated.

Comment: Thanks just supply in left will also be 12V with 4 ohm load

Comment: You mean, the magnetics is run from 12 V instead of 48 V ?

Comment: yes both run with 12V now

Comment: Oh, then just use the left schematic and you're done :-)

Comment: I just opened a new question directly related to this circuit: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/265634/a-question-about-heating-of-a-slowly-turning-off-mosfet I would be very glad to have your comment if I need heat-sink. thanks