# A question about heating of a slowly turning off MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, heatsink

I have an N-Channel MOSFET IRF530 with its [datasheet](http://www.vishay.com/docs/91019/91019.pdf) used in the following circuit:

[image]

When turned on it passes 2.5A current.
So I first wanted to make some calculations to check whether I would need a heat-sink if it was continuously at saturated/on state.

Following the knowledge from this [document](http://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-093.pdf): 
For any power dissipation P (in watts), one can calculate the effective temperature differential (ΔT) in °C as:

ΔT = P × θ

where θ is the total applicable thermal resistance

[image]

The series thermal resistances at above model shows the total thermal resistance path a device may see. Therefore the total θ for calculation purposes is the sum, i.e.,

\$\theta_{JA} = \theta_{JC} + \theta_{CA}\$. Given the ambient temperature \$T_A\$, P, and θ, then \$T_J\$ can be calculated.

So in my case TJmax = 175°C,  Junction-to-Ambient θ given as θJA = 62°C/W

\$R_{DS}{(on)}\$ = 0.16 ohm

Since current is 2.5A

\$P = I^2 R = (2.5)^2(0.16) = 1W \$, so ΔT the temperature rise becomes:

ΔT = P × θ = 1 × 62 = 62°C

Let's say the ambient temperature is 35°C, then the total temperature becomes

35 + 62 = 97°C which is smaller than 175°C

First conclusion was the MOSFET does not need a heatsink.

**Until I simulated the circuit...**

What I noticed is that, in my application the MOSFET turns on very quickly, passes almost a constant 2.5A through itself for few seconds, and turns-off slowly. And during turn-off there is a time interval where I × V product becomes quite high.

Here is the voltage and current plot in LTspice where it shows how the MOSFET turns-on at time zero, stays on and turns-off slowly:

[image]

And here is what LTspice shows for the power during this time interval:

[image]

**My questions are**

1-) What kind of logical reasoning should I follow at this point? Pmax = 30W here. If I use the procedure I wrote at the beginning the temperature rise becomes

ΔT = P × θ = 30 × 62 = 1861°C

But this is insane. If I switch the MOSFET on and off many times I can feel by finger it really gets hot. In my application a push-button switch turns on the MOSFET and an RC delay turns it off. It doesn't repeat continuously I mean. Do I need a heat-sink here?

2-) This is about the power during on time. In LTpice during the on time as you see the MOSFET's power is around 500mW but I calculate the power dissipation as:

\$P = I^2  R = (2.5)^2 ( 0.16) = 1W\$ using data sheet's \$R_{ds(on)}\$. In my case \$V_{gs}\$ is 15V not 10V. Can that be the reason for this difference?

**edit:**

For @jbord39, power at the load R1 shown together with the MOSFET's power below:

[image]

Comment: Could you show the circuit you used to generate this simulation?

Comment: sure i edit right now

Comment: It may also be very helpful to show the power in the loads as well, in the same chart as the power in the FET; i.e.: the current through the mosfet times the voltage drop across the two parallel loads (which will be the same).  I think this power spike is just due to the higher resistance encountered when the MOSFET has not yet fully turned on, so as current flows through it burns more power; P = I^2*R.  Switching it faster should reduce the power, if this is the case (a ~2s turn on time is very slow)

Comment: @jbord39 made an edit for you

Comment: "turn-off time" is slow due to RC delay, turn-on time is fast.

Comment: @jbord39 the data sheet says Maximum Power Dissipation is 88W. is that the same kind of power of the MOSFET LTspice shows?

Comment: Looking at the power graph with the total power shown I think will help explain the situation.  The MOSFET power is still only a small portion of the total power.  And it occurs during the turn off of the MOSFET.  This makes sense, it happens during all switching events even for digital circuits.  Especially since the current through a inductor cannot change instantaneously.  You will need an active pulldown on the MOSFET to reduce the power further.

Comment: It makes sense because as the MOSFET turns off it goes from low resistance to medium resistance to high resistance to very high resistance.  During the middle phase of this, the MOSFET is burning a lot more power.  I think your simulations look correct.

Comment: what is "an active pulldown on the MOSFET"

Comment: I mean a way to drive the MOSFET gate low, rather than allow the built up charge to leak through your 1Meg +470kOhm + 5Meg pot to ground, which will take some time.  For example another NPN BJT which can discharge the gate charge (in parallel with the zener) when your switch is open, if you must keep the current resistor sizes.

Comment: Or you could replace your SPST switch with a SPDT and connect the 'off' position so it connects to ground (rather than just floating).

Comment: Could you draw as an answer? Thnjs

Comment: @user16307 Don't forget that the power you see is *instantaneous*, so what you need is the actual average of it: select an ingeret number of periods and then `Ctrl+RClick` on the waveform's label to integrate it. As it has been mentioned, as long as the power peak doesn't go against its datasheet specifications, you're safe considering the average.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen there is only one period it is a push button.  i chose interval between 7.1 and 8.5 sec which covers the peak as see my edit the average is about 16W I think the maximum is 88W right? so is it safe without heat-sink in this case? but for temperature increase it is 16 x 62 = 992°C increase now. but in this case can we neglect it since it is not continuous current?

Comment: @user16307 The temperature doesn't change that abruptly. It's actually a lot slower. SPICE-wise it's modeled as a Cauer RC ladder. If you're only using your switch for a push-button application, then it's quite safe to consider only the ON/OFF states, since there are, virtually, no transitions.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen isnt turn off a transition? btw are these temperature formulas for constant continous current? so in my case we dont follow this because the temperature cannot rise that mush in a second? thanks

Comment: @user16307 What I really don't understand is why do you need such large time constants at the gate? Why would you need a `1Meg` resistor? If what you need is a hold time, and such low switching times, why not use a relay? Instead of wasting dissipated power, you make it useful by keeping the switch closed/opened. There are switches that consume very little.

Comment: this way i can set the hold time by a poti. poti will set RC delay and hold time. it will be used once in a day. push button will be pushed one or two times. pwr consumption is not issue. i need 20 of this circuit. has to be cheap. i tried hundred times it works until now. i just wanted to be sure if i need heatsink. time can be set from 2 sec to 10 sec. i could do this with opamp but it takes long time to build and requires extra components and extra pwr supply. wiring is long. needed a simplest circuit.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Do you think regarding red power curve for MOSFET's turn-off in my question, the MOSFET is safe? In the data sheet there is a plot called "Maximum Safe Operating Area" and The Photon mentioned and tried to explain about it. I'm not exceeding any max ratings and use a 6 C/W heatsink, but I still cannot be sure if MOSFET would be fine for yers of use. Untill now even without heatsink I made 100 tests and MOSFET didnt burn up. I use heatsink now but this "Safe Operating Area" bothers me. I installed many of these thats why my concern. I would be glad to have your opinion.

Comment: @user16307 Consider the brute facts: average Id~1.2A, avg Vd~25, Pd~1.2*25~30 (a bit more than the peak shown). The pulse is ~1s. If you use the graph in ThePhoton's answer, draw a line at 25V and one at 1.2A and see where they meet. Then, it looks like the slopes for pulse durations are linearly spaced, so, just oggling, it looks like it's about at the limit. This, *without* heatsink. *With* it, you'll have a better power dissipation capability. From my point of view, I'd say you're safe, but it's only by these gross approximations. I still don't know why use such large time constants.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen My concern was since this makes a peak very quickly first at the junction, I wasnt sure if junction is exposed to 30W suddenly how quickly the temperature would be effected by the heatsink. When I use the heatsink the case doesnt get very hot anymore; but since I cannot measure the junction it was a mystery. On the other hand I found LTspice has a new feature which measures junction temperature and case temperature for some NMOSFETs: http://www.linear.com/solutions/5445 They also have one for heatsink: http://www.linear.com/solutions/7415

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen They have something called "User defined" when you use SOAtherm but I couldnt set it for IRF530. Another thing is using SOA-HeatSink doesnt change junction temperature in their model if Im not wrong. Maybe I should open as a new question but have you dealt with setting a  "User defined" NMOSFET? I couldnt set it for IRF530. It seems only two liens to be modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I use the procedure I wrote at the beginning the temperature rise becomes
>
> ΔT = P × θ = 30 × 62 = 1861°C
>
> But this is insane. ... Do I need a heat-sink here?

You are neglecting to consider the heat capacity of the chip. This acts like a capacitor in the thermal equivalent circuit, connected between Tj and (some arbitrarily defined) ground, which prevents the chip from heating up instantaneously. Unfortunately you are unlikely to find good data on exactly what the value of this capacitor should be.

You can refer to the safe operating area curve for your MOSFET:

[image]

Based on this it's probably safest to keep your switching time below 10 ms, instead of close to 1 s as you have currently.

Comment: if i push button couple of times, which means if the slow turn-off occurs very rare, then the transistor doesn't get hot i check with my fingers. but i repeat it continuously i can feel it gets really hot. in my application it will be pushed once or two times not more than that. but i still want to be sure if i need a heat sink here. i will wire 20 of this circuit parallel thats why i wanted to be sure if i need heatsink here or i can ignore it. wanted to quantify besides checking with fingers.

Comment: how to change switching time? the RC decay causes it

Comment: It could still be heating up enough in a small volume internally, so that the chip is being damaged, even if it is not hot enough to burn your finger.

Comment: How to change switching time? Reduce R or reduce C. If you're using RC also to delay the turn-off after the switch is opened, try using a one-shot instead.

Comment: the thing is i could do it with an opamp or one shot but it requires extra power supply and more components. when i reduce RC the peak power remains the same but i will try to narrow it to 10ms as you suggested

Comment: Peak power will remain pretty much the same. But the total energy converted to heat in the FET is given by power integrated over time.

Comment: the only problem is i can only narrow it that much if the on time is set to 2 seconds. if i set it to 5 sec for instance i have to use larger R so peak range exceeds 10ms.

Comment: I'm re-reading your answer. Is this "safe operating area curve" considers no heat-sink? I mean regarding my question, I found a very big heatsink with 6C/W thermal resistance to use. But since I will use at linear region for couple of seconds I take the average power as 16W and heatsink would save the MOSFET. But the MOSFET in my question still doesn't fit "safe operating area curve" even though it would dissipate enough power to not to exceed max junction temperature. Do you think using a proper heatsink I can disregard that safe operating limits?

Comment: Like it says on the graph, this is with whatever heatsink is needed to keep the case temperature at 25 C.

Comment: i dont understand, but thanks anyway

Comment: It say's right on the graph: "Tc = 25 C". That means to make the graph valid, you have to provide whatever heat sink is needed to keep the case at 25 C. If you are just driving low duty cycle pulses, that might be no heat sink at all. If you are driving the part continuously in linear mode it might be a really big heatsink with water cooling.

Comment: In my case it is neither continuous nor a typical sharp pulse. Not periodic, a push button is pushed only one time. The power of MOSFET is like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlrWK.png As you see it makes a peak to around 30W; total turn off time takes couple of seconds. I first calculate the temperature raise for 15W dissipation(I take the average of the curve) by using a heatsink with 6W/C and this makes me think that I dont exceed 175 C and MOSFET is safe. But then when I look at your figure for V and I it seems MOSFET in my case is not safe.

Comment: I'm very sorry for digging it too much but I came across a very interesting article called: "Modeling Safe Operating Area Behavior of N-channel MOSFETs" at: http://www.linear.com/solutions/5239 There is a very nice feature called SOAtherm which I never heard before. It shows in their video how one can simulate junction temperature. But the models only include some MOSFETs. But there is also some thing called "User defined" there. But the article doesn't shown how to modify for another NMOSFET. I just wondered if you had used this before since I couldn't find any other info on it.

Comment: ..and here is the video how to use this feature: http://www.linear.com/solutions/5445 It is very clear, just that it seems it is limited for only some MOSFETs, and they dont tell how one can modify lines of code for another one like IRF530 in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Your simulations look very reasonable.  You are switching 120W and are burning about 30W in the MOSFET when turning off.  If you want to prevent the FET from heating up so much, you need to switch it off faster.

Right now, when the switch opens, the charge on the gate has to slowly leak through the 1Meg + 470kOhm + 5Meg pot before reaching ground.

So there is more time (compared to if the gate was discharged more quickly) which the MOSFET is weakly conducting/higher-R (compared to on-state).  This increases the power.  This is exacerbated a bit since the inductor current cannot change instantaneously (and so will force current through the higher resistance FET) as the MOSFET turns off.

Alternatively, the pullup path is just through the 1Meg resistor.

You can replace your SPST switch with a SPDT switch and connect the "off" setting to ground (rather than floating).  This should speed up the gate turn-off and prevent you from burning as much power per switching event.

Comment: İt is not Spst it is a push button. Could you draw what you mean i still didnt get it

Comment: @dicksonchargepump, pushbutton switches are available with either SPST or SPDT electrical configuration.